# How can Android deep links be made to work from the Chrome OS browser?

Tags: android, url, deep-linking, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

On a web page, I have a URL that is a deep link to my Android app. It is of the form `myapp://myrequest?url=someurl`

This is captured via an intent filter in the app manifest. I use `getIntent().getData.getQueryParameter("url")` in the `onCreate()` of my activity to get the `someurl` part, which is what I need for further processing. The intent filter is of the form:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="myapp"
        android:host="myrequest" />
</intent-filter>
```

It works perfectly on Android devices and from Android browsers installed via APK and/or the Play store on ChromeOS devices. But it does not work from the native ChromeOS browser. When the link is clicked, a dialog box opens with the message:

> Google Chrome OS can't open this page

How can this be made to work? Do I have to format the URL differently? Do I have to add and/or modify the intent filter? Or is there some entirely different method I must use for ChromeOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error I noticed that the native ChromeOS browser does not like to use custom schemes to open Android apps.
If you instead use `http` or `https` the browser should ask you if you want to open the URL using your app.

Example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="my.app.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

To test launching your app, use `window.open("https://my.app.com");` in the browser console.